# Django query after multiple keywords in database

Tags: python, django

I have a line of code that looks up in my database after Fields containing the string **Waiting**, but I also want it to look for the field named **Timeout**.

My current code looks like this:

```
query_running = Usertasks.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).filter(TaskStatus="Waiting")
```

This works perfectly but I need to also search for the string `Timeout`

I tried code that looked like this, but this doesn't work.

```
query_running = Usertasks.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).filter(TaskStatus="Waiting", "Timeout")
```

And just to be clear, it should search for either word. Both words are not going to be present at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Django's Queryset "in"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in):

If you want user = request.user AND TaskStatus = Waiting or Timeout:

```
query_running = Usertasks.objects.filter(user=request.user, TaskStatus__in=["Waiting", "Timeout"])
```

If not:

```
query_running = Usertasks.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(TaskStatus__in=["Waiting", "Timeout"])
```

Comment: @LesnieSncheider may i suggest you write it as: `Usertasks.objects.filter(user=request.user, TaskStatus__in=["Waiting", "Timeout"])` you dont need the `.all()` or the extra `.filter()` -- cheers!

Comment: Also you can filter everything at the same time. I'll update my answer to contain this and @JavierBuzzi sugestion.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi the `.all` is there because im using this function to query other things also in my HTML. So it's there for a reason. I just haven't posted that part :-)

Comment: I would need to see more code, but my first hunch is you dont need it -- unless you're building a query ..regardless its a noop operation.